# Touch Scroll not working in some devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am designing website in wordpress, i almost completed the website design , but i came across a problem in some devices where the website is not scrolling in touch

Here is the website http://paprix.com/qmysap

If i scrolled from ipad, or in some android devices touch scroll is not working, but at the same if i work from iphone 5 or 6 touch scroll is working fine, i cant able to find where the issue lies

body and html tag consits of

```
overflow:hidden;
```

even i changed it to

```
overflow:auto;
```

but still i cant able to find the issue of why it is not working in the device, even in chrome responsive simulator it is not working, please help me to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, as there was issue lies on the skroller.js file, when i remove the file, now the website is working fine and smooth